# Get specific record at top from any specific user’s data

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

```
user_artworks = artworks.aggregate([{
    '$match': {
        "user_id": user_id
    }
}, {
    '$sort': {
        'created_at': pymongo.DESCENDING
    }
}, {
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'artwork_images',
        'localField': '_id',
        'foreignField': 'artwork_id',
        'as': "artwork_images"
    }
}, {
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'artwork_moods',
        'localField': '_id',
        'foreignField': 'artwork_id',
        'as': "moods"
    }
}, {
    '$lookup': {
        'from': 'artwork_mediums',
        'localField': '_id',
        'foreignField': 'artwork_id',
        'as': "mediums"
    }
}, {
    '$lookup': {
        'from':
        'artwork_collaborators',
        'localField':
        '_id',
        'foreignField':
        'artwork_id',
        'pipeline': [{
            '$lookup': {
                'from': "users",
                'localField': "user_id",
                'foreignField': "_id",
                'as': "collaborator_info"
            }
        }],
        'as':
        "artwork_collaborator",
    },
}, {
    '$facet': {
        'data': [{
            '$skip': skip
        }, {
            '$limit': page_size
        }],
        'metadata': [{
            '$count': 'total',
        }],
    }
}])
```

I have above query to update like this, so that if i send artwork_id in match with user_id, then the results show that artwork_id at top and then all the conditions like they are working right now with pagination

OR

If there is not any solution to update above query with match then is there any option that i can show some specific artwork_id at top from searched user's artwork collection with pagination(above query can help with schema to understand the problem)

Comment: 6 `$lookup` in a small aggregation pipeline smells like a very poor data design. Usually in NoSQL databases like MongoDB you much less number of collections (and joins) than the number of tables in according relational DBMS. NoSQL like MongoDB databases are not optimized for joins, some of them do not even support joins at all.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you are right about joins, but to query in related tables separately, increase in response time, so need to add joins or lookups to keep response time less, well thats a separate story not concerned at the moment

Comment: You may design the application that you have all data in one single collection - that might be the right direction.

Comment: ok, lets give me an idea i want to learn from you if you can, i have a social app like facebook, which has user profile, friends, posts, comments, sub-comments, likes for posts, comments etc, how can i manage it one single collection, i think i need to handle it in multiple collections like we handle in sub tables in any RDBMS

Comment: Maybe not one single collection, but it should be much less than tables in RDBMS.